# Convert function to async function without redefining

Tags: javascript, node.js

how do me change function to async function in java script no redefining function or editing code and attaching `async` to function state ment

```js
f = () => 0;
console.log(f);  // [Function (anonymous)]
console.log(asyncify(f));  // [AsyncFunction (anonymous)]

console.log(f());  // 0
console.log(asyncify(f)());  // Promise { 0 }
asyncify(f)().then(console.log)  // 0
```

asking why is forbiden

Comment: async functions and normal functions have different `constructor` properties.. however trying to change a function's constructor, I dunno how :l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the `asyncify` function, we see that it gets passed a function `f` and must also return an async function. So it has the form of:

```
accept function `f` ----> return Async Function
```

The above definition can be written using arrow functions:

```
const asyncify = f => (async () => {})
```

Above, we see `(async () => {})` is the Async Function that is being returned, and that async function currently has an empty body `{}`. We can also remove the parenthesis around it as this is not needed, I've mainly included it for clarity.
Looking at the result you're after, you want to return a Promise from the above Async Function that resolves to the return value of `f()`. One could achieve this by explicitly returning a Promise that resolves to your value:

```
const asyncify = f => async () => new Promise(resolve => resolve(f()))
```

But the above code has a few redundancies. An `async` function will automatically return a Promise, that resolves to the value that gets returned from it. So it can instead be written as:

```
const asyncify = f => async () => f();
```

This will get the result that you're after. However, we're ignoring the fact that `f()` might need to get arguments passed to it. To solve this, we can pass some arguments into our `async` function, and forward them down to our `f` function to use. To specify a variable amount of arguments, we can use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

```
const asyncify = f => async (...args) => f(...args);
```

With all that, you'll get the following output in Node:

```
const asyncify = f => async (...args) => f(...args);
const f = () => 0;
console.log(f);  // [Function: f]
console.log(asyncify(f));  // [AsyncFunction (anonymous)]

console.log(f());  // 0
console.log(asyncify(f)());  // Promise { 0 }
asyncify(f)().then(console.log)  // 0
```

```js
const asyncify = f => async (...args) => f(...args);
const f = () => 0;
console.log(f);  // [Function (anonymous)]
console.log(asyncify(f));  // [AsyncFunction (anonymous)]

console.log(f());  // 0
console.log(asyncify(f)());  // Promise { 0 }
asyncify(f)().then(console.log)  // 0
```

Comment: Side note: This code does **not** make a synchronous function asynchronous. For a function to be asynchronous, it needs to be using inbuilt asynchronous primitives like `fetch()`, `setTimeout()`, `requestAnimationFrame()` etc. that exist in your environment. Look into [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) or [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) in node if you want to run synchronous code in separate threads.